# Find file, Edit text within files

Tags: sed, scripting, grep, osx

I am trying to find a file and then edit the text within these files.
This is what I have so far, but sadly I'm not that well versed. Help please?

```
grep -rl "wrongtext" ~/Library/Calendars


/Users/foo/Library/Calendars/foo.caldav/foo.calendar/Info.plist
/Users/foo/Library/Calendars/foo.calendar.caldav/foo.calendar.calendar/Info.plist
/Users/foo/Library/Calendars/foo.calendar.caldav/Info.plist
/Users/foo/Library/Calendars/foo.calendar.caldav/Info.plist
/Users/foo/Library/Calendars/CalendarCache
```

Then...

```
sed -i '' 's/wrongtext/righttext/g’
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more readable, but your question is not clear to me, please describe the problem in more details.

Comment: You can just put the folder after the sed as it accepts multiple files and won't change anything in the ones without `wrongtext`. `sed -i '' 's/wrongtext/righttext/g’ ~/Library/Calendars/*`

Comment: `Calendar Cache` is a sqlite database. You need to exclude this file. It may also have a backup file in this location. You seem to looking to change `Info.plist` then try  `grep -rlZ "wrongtext" ~/Library/Calendars/*/Info.plist`

Answer (score 3):

That should do it:

```
grep -rlZ "wrongtext" ~/Library/Calendars | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/wrongtext/righttext/g'
```

I added the `-Z` parameter to `grep` to add a zero byte instead of a newline after every filename. So the command works also with strange filenames. `xargs` then reads the input delimited by the zero byte with `-0` and calls the `sed` command.

Comment: Add `''` after the `-i` option or OS X's sed will barf and not execute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Defiantly getting somewhere. However I get this now:             

OutputOutputOutputOutputOutput
OutputOutputOutputOutputOutput
OutputOutputOutputOutputOutpu
: No such file or directory

Comment: @user2720970 Sry, I had a strange character in the command, try now

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It does not like the **-O**

`grep -rlZ "wrongtext" ~/Library/Calendars | xargs sed -i '' 's/wrongtext/righttext/g'`

Comment: you really need `''`  after `sed -i` ? I don't have osx at hand.

Comment: Yes, you really do...

Comment: it is a -0 not -O

Comment: Yes, its a numerical 0